# Inform ViewModel that something happened in another ViewModel, Devexpress, Winforms

Tags: winforms, mvvm, devexpress

My Problem is the following: When I do something (in this case adding new student) in one ViewModel, I want to be done something (in this case call RaisePropertyChanged) in another ViewModel.

In this case MainWindowViewModel's corresponding View displays the student list.
Then I open StudentWindowViewModel's corresponding view, which is used to add student in the database. When I add the student, I want it to be immediately reflected in my student list.

This is my code, but it doesn't refresh the student list.

```
[POCOViewModel()]
public class MainWindowViewModel
{

    // getting list of students
    public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; } = MainWindowMethods.GetStudents();


    private readonly StudentWindowViewModel viewModel = new StudentWindowViewModel();
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
         viewModel.ItemsChanged += () =>
         {
             this.RaisePropertyChanged(x => x.Students);
         };
    }

}
```

This is StudentWindowViewModel

```
public delegate void MyDel();

[POCOViewModel()]
public class StudentWindowViewModel
{
    public virtual string StudentCode { get; set; } = "";
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; } = "";
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }

    public event MyDel ItemsChanged;

    //add student in database
    public void AddStudent()
    {
        StudentWindowMethods.AddStudent(new Student
        {
            StudentCode = StudentCode,
            FirstName = FirstName,
            LastName = LastName,
            Age = Age
        });

        //this is null, and event isn't invoked
        ItemsChanged?.Invoke();

        StudentCode = "";
        FirstName = "";
        LastName = "";
        Age = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `BindingList<T>`?

Comment: You mean Change List<T> to BindingList<T> will solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for `BindingList<T>`.

To have complex two-way data binding to list controls like `ComboBox`, `ListBox` or `DataGridView`, you need to use an implementation of [`IBindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist(v=vs.110).aspx) as `DataSource` of the control. As an option you can rely on [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx). This way each add/remove in the underlying data source will be reflected in the control UI immediately.

In fact you add/remove an item to/from a `BindingList<T>` a `ListChanged` event will be raised by the list which cause the data-bound controls like `DataGridView` reset bindings and reflect changes in the UI.

While using `BindingList<T>` allows the bound control be updated when adding and removing items, but to reflect property changes immediately, `T` should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, but will INotifypropertyChanged fired when a student object will be added to the list?

Comment: Not automatically. In fact when adding/removing items, a `ListChange` will be raised. If you are interested to raising `PropertyChanged` when adding an item to the student list, then make sure you have subscribed to its `ListChanged` event and in the handler, raise `PropertyChanged` event for `Students`.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you are using `DataGridView` for data-binding, it will automatically use the `ListChanged` event of the `BidningList<T>` and update the control. But if for any reason, you are interested to `PropertyChanged`, follow what I described in the previous comment.

Comment: In my code above, I am raising ItemsChanged event but when I debug, it is always null. I think the problem is there..

Comment: I am using devexpress gridView